# "export 'createStore' was not found in 'redux'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@redux-saga/core/dist/redux-saga-core.esm.js 1343:21-28
"export 'compose' was not found in 'redux'
 @ ./node_modules/redux-saga/dist/redux-saga-core-npm-proxy.esm.js
 @ ./src/store.js
 @ ./src/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js

WARNING in ./src/store.js 6:21-32
"export 'createStore' was not found in 'redux'
 @ ./src/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js
```

I'm facing the problem of creating a redux store. Here, I've added the sample code. If I remove the provider from App.js, it's working fine. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store'

const App = () => {
  return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Layout/>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'

import reducers from './redux';
import sagas from './sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

export const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)

sagaMiddleware.run(sagas)
```

reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as auth } from './AuthRedux'

const reducers = combineReducers({
    auth
});

export default reducers;
```

sagas

```
import { takeLatest, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import api from '../middleware/api';
import { AuthTypes } from '../redux/AuthRedux'
import { signupSaga } from './AuthSaga'

export default function * root () {
    const sagaIndex = [
        yield takeLatest(AuthTypes.SIGNUP, signupSaga, api),
    ];
    yield all(sagaIndex)
}
```

I guess it has something to do with the redux and how I import stuff, but I'm not sure what's wrong there.

Thanks

Comment: Reproducible example on https://codesandbox.io/ would be helpful

Comment: There is nothing here that strikes me as wrong.  The most likely culprit is that somewhere in your various configuration files (webpack, etc) you have told your app that the location of the module `redux` is something other than `./node_modules/redux`

Answer (score 0):

In the store.js replace

```js
export const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)
```

with

```js
export const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {},
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)
```

Just an arrow in the dark coz it worked for me maybe it should work for you